# msbuild - difference between using PROPERTY or ITEM to store values

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

In my existing `MSBuild` XML, I have this

```
    <Exec
        EchoOff="true"
        StandardOutputImportance="low"
        StandardErrorImportance="low"
        IgnoreExitCode="true"
        ConsoleToMSBuild="true" 
        Command='
            "$(CompilerExe)" ^
                $(HWProcessor) ^
                $(IncludeDirs) ^
                $(CompilerOptions) ^
                $(CompileDefines) ^
                "$(CPPFILE)" ^
                -MM
    '>
        <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="output_cppdeps"/>
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="exitcode_cppdeps"/>
    </Exec>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Item_output_cppdeps Include="$(output_cppdeps)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After task `Exec` is executed, the output `output_cppdeps` is transformed into an `Item`; is there a functional reason why?

Are there more operations you can do on an `Item` vs a `Property`? Or is it simply style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there more operations you can do on an Item vs a Property? Or is it simply style?

Before answering this question, we need to know about the functions of `Property` and `Item`.

**Item Functions**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886422.aspx

**Property Functions**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx

So Item and Property have different functions. According to the description [Comparing Properties and Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997067.aspx)：

> MSBuild properties and items are both used to pass information to
>   tasks, evaluate conditions, and store values that can be referenced
>   throughout the project file.

We could convert `Property` to `Item` or `Item` to `Property`, in this case, we could do more operations on an `Item` VS a `Property` or use Property`s function on`Item`. For example,  set Item Metadata as properties within MSBuild script:

```
<ItemGroup>  
  <OutputDir Include="KeyFiles\;Certificates\" />  
</ItemGroup>  
<PropertyGroup>  
  <OutputDirList>@(OutputDir)</OutputDirList>  
</PropertyGroup>
```

After that, we could use `property` function on the `Item`.

Refer to this link for details: [Comparing Properties and Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997067.aspx)

So your understanding is correct, "**there are more operations you can do on an Item vs a Property, it is not simply style**"

Hope this helps.